# Why am I question banned?

Tags: support

I know that I am question banned for asking poorly-received questions.

The thing is though, I don't understand why my questions are bad.

Does anyone mind taking a look through the poorly-received questions I've asked and telling me how I can improve my questions for the future?

I'd really appreciate someone telling me what I'm doing wrong that gets [for example this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1168438/get-my-taskbar-back) (which is, IMO, a completely fine question) so heavily downvoted. I'd like to learn what a good question *actually* looks like and learn why my questions are in fact bad.

Comment: Many of your questions use vague and wishy-washy language such as "worst", "best", "terrible" and so on. We are a technical site and precise language appeals to us. What you call "the worst ping you have ever seen" seems pretty reasonable to someone who used to have to use a 33.6k baud modem years ago. Avoid being vague, give hard facts, don't use fuzzy language, when using pretty graphs it helps to explain exactly what you are showing as picture detail can be lost when scaled.

Comment: @Mokubai ok thank you for your feedback, this is potentially the most helpful so far and I'm going to try my hardest to reduce the amount of sweeping hyperbole in my questions.

Comment: @Mokubai out of interest, was it actually normal for ping times to consistently exceed 2000 ms when pinging one's own router/modem if they were using the set up you've just described?

Comment: @theonlygusti - No; It is not normal.  It could mean several different things.  But what those things might be, are outside of the scope this question, and the comment section in general.

Comment: @Ramhound Mokubai was telling me my language was over-exaggerated, which I appreciate, but I honestly couldn't imagine people getting pings of 2+ seconds when stood right next to their router even decades ago. I am still going to change the language I use in my questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have asked 30 questions:

- You have +7 in upvotes
- You have -6 in downvotes on undeleted questions
- You have -4 in downvotes on **deleted** questions (deleted question count towards your question ban).

Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) would be a good start for improving your questions.

> How do I view my deleted questions?

From [How do I find questions or answers that I've deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted):

> [Since June 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492), deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 60 days, can be seen using the "deleted recent questions" and "deleted recent answers" links on the questions and answers tabs in your user profile.
>
> [image]

See also [How do I view my old deleted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217169/how-do-i-view-my-old-deleted-questions)

Comment: But what is actually wrong with my questions? I feel like they fit the criteria defined by that help topic, but I must be wrong, so I was really hoping someone would be able to point out the exact problems to me. Also, how do I view my deleted questions?

Comment: I cannot answer for all of them, but e.g. the WIfi and ping questions were skipped by my after reading things like 'horrible', 'disgusting' and 'worst I have ever seen'.  Not precisely specific and useful quantifications.

As for the https://superuser.com/questions/1071927/upgrade-to-windows-10-on-old-windows-7-desktop question: The answer to bad is 'Maybe', or 'it depends', I see no research as to why it is slow. And without that there is no answer if something else would make it faster. Etc etc. See David'd link for a much better answer on how to post a good question.

Comment: @theonlygusti See updated answer.

Comment: Don't forget we can see your edit summaries "For some reason I thought it was cool to pretend I'd done it to a friend. Now I realise that may have led to a ridiculous number of downvotes and so edited it to be more truthful."

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't think it matters, that's me appealing to humans. The original question as it stood was not worthy of downvotes imo.

Comment: @theonlygusti Your opinion doesn't really matter here. People can downvote for [any reason they like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397). Usually because they think the question "does not show any research effort" - yours doesn't, "is not clear - yours is clear, or "is not useful" - yours isn't as it's not a real problem - it can be answered by "don't do that".

Comment: @DavidPostill "How do I use the command line to get the taskbar back?" — "Don't do that." Doesn't sound like much of an answer to me, but hey you know your way around this site so I'll take your word for it. I'd like to point out that the top 5 most highly voted questions on the site show no research effort. Thanks though, I realise now that users are just humans, but I really am looking for some explicit tips

Comment: @Hennes you skipped over it ignoring the ping tables and graphs I meticulously plotted? Ignoring the tech information about the router and firmware? Ignoring the dslreports speed test score for a quantitative evaluation of bufferbloat, linespeed etc.? How do I prevent people from doing what you did when I ask questions in the future?

Comment: Make sure you have a good title and a good start. If I read two lines and decide to move on after that it does not matter what the rest is.

Comment: @Hennes ok I'll try that

Comment: Use the right tags. [Get my taskbar back](//superuser.com/q/1168438) is about Windows 8.1 and is tagged Windows 10.

Comment: @theonlygusti What graphs? I don't see any graphs in your question.  Besides, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1071927/upgrade-to-windows-10-on-old-windows-7-desktop) question, asks for an opinion.  Yes; "Would accepting Microsoft's offer of upgrading to Windows 10 make my computer faster?" is asking for our opinion.  Your question should have described the performance problems, so we could have solved your actual problem

Comment: @Ramhound the graphs are on the ping times question. And again for the upgrading question, I'm not good enough to know what information I have to provide to better help people answer, but if people tell me I will gladly provide it. I provided all the diagnostic information I could think of to make the question as objectively answerable as possible.

Comment: @theonlygusti - You have two **identical** ping questions.  Neither have graphs in them currently.  Are you talking about a third ping question?  I am talking about [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1225087/how-to-optimise-lede-router-for-minecraft) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1225057/high-pings-within-online-games-even-though-command-line-ping-looks-good).  Yes; **They are identical.**

Comment: @Ramhound [Terrible (inconsistent) ping to own router](//superuser.com/q/1216927)

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, I thought Hennes was talking about [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1216927/terrible-inconsistent-ping-to-own-router). You're right though, it's more likely they're talking about one of the others, _which still include (IMO) lots of diagnostic information_. Like, I took 100 samples in-game for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1225057/high-pings-within-online-games-even-though-command-line-ping-looks-good) to try to provide as accurate information as possible and had to manually process them in excel.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd really appreciate someone telling me what I'm doing wrong that
>   gets for example [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1168438/get-my-taskbar-back) question (which is, IMO, a completely fine
>   question) so heavily down voted.

In that particular example.  It appears simply rebooting resolved your problem.  Honestly, this indicates a lack of research, or you simply were to quick to ask us the question.

> - [High pings within online games even though command-line ping looks good](https://superuser.com/questions/1225057/high-pings-within-online-games-even-though-command-line-ping-looks-good)
> - [How to optimize LEDE router for minecraft?](https://superuser.com/questions/1225087/how-to-optimise-lede-router-for-minecraft)

Your initial question was fine, but you ended up asking the same identical question 3 hours later, for a reason I cannot determine.

> - [Get better wifi speeds for one device, router doesn't support QoS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1209127/get-better-wifi-speeds-for-one-device-router-doesnt-support-qos)
>
> > I am wondering, is there an app or something I can do on my macOS
> >     Sierra Macbook Pro to be able to increase its wifi speeds while
> >     perhaps being detrimental to the speeds of the other devices in my
> >     home?

Asking if there is something you can do or an application you can use, to increase your WiFi speeds, is an extremely broad question.

> - [How to remove nodes from a path?](https://superuser.com/questions/1198116/how-to-remove-nodes-from-a-path)
> - How do I get my requests to this address to take a more efficient route?

This question shows you did not really do enough research on how DNS works.  You knew enough to provide the route your connection was taking, which indicates you understood DNS well enough to do that, but didn't know it cannot be changed by the end user?  Despite the low quality question, you received an excellent answer, but didn't accept it.

> - [cURL command units of Dload speed?](https://superuser.com/questions/1071920/curl-command-units-of-dload-speed)
>
> > What unit is Average Dload given in?

This just might be me.  If I were to ask a question, then realized I didn't comprehend what I was looking at 30 minutes later, I would have just deleted my own question.  While I don't normally suggest removing a question, this question existing with 0 votes, and without an accepted answer actually hurt you.  In this case, the question being deleted, actually would have been a positive.

> [Stop Microsoft's Remote Desktop disconnecting me when another user
>   logs on](https://superuser.com/questions/1117946/stop-microsofts-remote-desktop-disconnecting-me-when-another-user-logs-on)
>
> > Is there a way to disable physical log-on while I am connected via
> >     Remote Desktop?

You asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1117946/stop-microsofts-remote-desktop-disconnecting-me-when-another-user-logs-on) that has received numerous answers already and don't indicate how your question is unique.

### Conclusion

If you had not asked that identical question you likely would not have been question banned.  It appears you are just barely question banned.  This does not mean the question should be deleted at this point.

It's existence, hurts you, now or in it's afterlife.  This means only positive actions can lift the question ban, or you can continue to submit high quality answers, and/or wait 6 months for single chance to ask another question.

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to go through all of these, I'm struggling to understand a couple of your comments though, I hope it's ok if I ask you to elaborate: you say that the QoS w/o QoS is an extremely broad question, but it has no solution apparently. I thought that's the exact opposite of the definition of broad? Also, the cURL comment; I don't understand why you think I can't comprehend what I've written. I understand it well.

Comment: Maybe my written communication needs work.

Comment: @theonlygusti You didn't ask about QoS (except you did but your question doesn't indicate that), you ask what software or action you could use, to help your wifi speeds.  You said you didn't comprehend it.  You answered your own question, after a short while, and ended up basically days by you miss interpreted the information (go check what you wrote)